# Weird font issue in chrome: two dots (Umlaut) above letter

Tags: html, font-face

[image]

I am facing a weird problem with my font. This has happened when I apply the bold version of AkzidenzGroteskBE font. What's wrong with it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the original text? seems to be a charset issue.

Comment: The original text is probably "Fotograﬁe" with a ﬁ ligature.

Comment: @nwellnhof yes, you right. But in chrome it shows as like this.

Comment: @Johannes link is private. Any idea which charset should I use for this type of issue.